# MySQL JOIN ON the one of two columns that doesn't match variable

Tags: mysql, database, where-clause

Let's jump right into it: I've got two simple tables set up in my MySQL database, a `users` table and a `matches` table. The `users` table holds, well, users. The `matches` table is meant to establish many-to-many connections between users and contains just two userID's.

What is want to query is a list of names of all matched users for the user with userID `1` but I can't wrap my head around it. The problem is that the userID (in this case `1`) could be in either one field and I don't have a clue in which one.

Just to clarify; I mean something like this (please don't mind the weird pseudo-code):

```
SELECT users.name 
FROM matches 
INNER JOIN users 
ON userId = (userId1 OR userId2 DEPENDS ON WHERE)
WHERE userId1 = '1' 
OR userId2 = '1';
```

Could you please tell me if this is possible with MySQL and if so, what I should look for/if you would be so kind, give a simple example.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The user of `or` in a join condition often prevents MySQL from using an index.  The use of `union` or `union all` makes the query rather cumbersome.  You can do what you want with `left outer join`:

```
SELECT coalesce(u1.name, u2.name) as name
FROM matches m LEFT JOIN
     users u1
     ON u.userId = m.userId1 AND m.userId2 = '1' LEFT JOIN
     users u2 
     ON u.userId = m.userId2 AND m.userId1 = '1'
WHERE '1' in (m.userId1, m.userId2);
```

This should take advantage of indexes on `users` for looking up the values.  If you want distinct names, then add the `distinct` keyword.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
SELECT DISTINCT u.name 
FROM matches m
INNER JOIN users u 
ON (u.userId = m.userId1 AND m.userId2 = '1') 
    OR (u.userId = m.userId2 AND m.userId1 = '1')
```

Added `DISTINCT` to avoid duplicate rows.

See this [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/820c9/5).

Comment: I think the Oliver is looking for a list of names of the matches for the person they are looking for excluding the searched individuals name.

Comment: I fixed the wrong tests ordering. Now, this query won't return the searched user unless there is a row containing the same user in both columns. If so, there's no reason to exclude it.

Comment: Thanks again! I like how simple the query is and how you stayed close to what I was looking for, this really helps me!

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
Select UserId1, UserId2
From Matches
Where UserId1 = 1
Union
Select UserId2, UserId1
From Matches
Where UserId2 = 1
```

Notice the order of the UserIds have been changed in the Select clause. This will give you a single list of matches with you searched user '1' in a single column and all their matches in the other.

This approach will require you then link in your users table as follows:

```
Select searchmatches.UserId1, searchmatches.UserId2, leftuser.Name, rightuser.name
From (
    Select UserId1, UserId2
    From Matches
    Where UserId1 = 1
    Union
    Select UserId2, UserId1
    From Matches
    Where UserId2 = 1
) searchmatches
inner join users leftuser userMatches.UserId1 = leftuser.UserId
inner join users rightuser userMatches.UserId2 = rightuser.UserId
```

Hope that Helps! If you want you can remove one of the inner joins to the users table as you know who the left user is as you searched on them!

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to do it that avoids excessive JOIN logic (to make sure SQL can use indexes on users.userId, matches.userId1, matches.userId2)

```
SELECT u.`name` 
FROM
matches AS m
JOIN users AS u
ON m.userId1=u.userId
AND m.userId2='1'

UNION

SELECT u.`name` 
FROM
matches AS m
JOIN users AS u
ON m.userId2=u.userId
AND m.userId1='1'
```